# A last part in query is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have some code, but `$query_last` is not working, previous  identica part `$query`  -without problems.

I Don't understand what the problem is.

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
        require 'connect_k.php';
        createMessage();
    }

    function createMessage(){
        global $connect;    
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $price_main = $_POST["price_main"];
        $date = $_POST["date"];
        $order_number = $_POST["order_number"];
        $query="INSERT INTO final(email,name,size,quantity,price)SELECT email,name,size,quantity,price FROM items_cart WHERE email like ('$email');";
        $query_del="DELETE FROM items_cart WHERE email like ('$email');";
        $query_upd="UPDATE final SET price_main='$price_main',order_number='$order_number',date='$date' WHERE email like ('$email');";
----problem is here----
        $query_last="INSERT INTO order(email,name,size,quantity,price,price_main,order_number,date)SELECT email,name,size,quantity,price,price_main,order_number,date FROM final WHERE email like ('$email');";
        mysqli_query ($connect,$query)or die (mysqli_error($connect));
        mysqli_query ($connect,$query_del)or die (mysqli_error($connect));
        mysqli_query ($connect,$query_upd)or die (mysqli_error($connect));
        mysqli_query ($connect,$query_last)or die (mysqli_error($connect));
        mysqli_close($connect);
    }
?>
```

Comment: `<?phpif`  is it typo? Because if it's not a typo mistake then nothing will work in your code.Alos function `}` is missed

Comment: You should let your code breathe more - spacing it more up and formatting makes it a lot easier to read - and in turn, easier to troubleshoot. And if there is any error from the query, `mysqli_error()` should tell you about it. You can also verify that the query works by running it in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: run this query in mysql directly and check what error is showing.

Comment: Any error you are getting when this code runs?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: your insert queries don't have `VALUES ()` part. Are you sure they are running? did you get any error

Comment: This code is all jumbled up. Clean, organized code makes mistakes more obvious.

Comment: @AlivetoDie `INSERT...SELECT` doesn't use `VALUES` if you match columns one-to-one.

Comment: `order` is a reserved keyword, and needs to be backticked 
- or you should rename the table altogether if its not too late - See this thread: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql

Comment: @Qirel   THHHAAAANKS!  THIS IST! QIREL it should be in 'answers' and i will accept it

Comment: Its a duplicate, so the question should really be closed by the duplicate instead ;-) better to gather information in one place!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"INSERT INTO order(email,name,size,quantity,price,price_main,order_number,date)SELECT email,name,size,quantity,price,price_main,order_number,date FROM final WHERE email like ('$email');";
```

[Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

order is a reserved keyword, and needs to be backticked or renamed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this I have modified my query

```
    $query_last  = "SELECT email,name,size,quantity,price,price_main,order_number,date FROM final WHERE email like ('$email');";
    mysqli_query ($connect,$query_last)or die (mysqli_error($connect));
    $new_last_qr ="INSERT INTO order(email,name,size,quantity,price,price_main,order_number,date) values (-- Set return values of $query_last --");
mysqli_query ($connect,$new_last_qr)or die (mysqli_error($connect));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that you are not escaping the query before passing it to the database, you should try using `addslashes` function for your inputs.

```
    function createMessage(){
        global $connect;    
        $email = addslashes($_POST["email"]);
        $price_main = addslashes($_POST["price_main"]);
        $date = addslashes($_POST["date"]);
        $order_number = addslashes($_POST["order_number"]);
        $query="INSERT INTO final(email,name,size,quantity,price)SELECT email,name,size,quantity,price FROM items_cart WHERE email like ('$email');";
        $query_del="DELETE FROM items_cart WHERE email like ('$email');";
        $query_upd="UPDATE final SET price_main='$price_main',order_number='$order_number',date='$date' WHERE email like ('$email');";
----problem is here----
        $query_last="INSERT INTO order(email,name,size,quantity,price,price_main,order_number,date)SELECT email,name,size,quantity,price,price_main,order_number,date FROM final WHERE email like ('$email');";
        mysqli_query ($connect,$query)or die (mysqli_error($connect));
        mysqli_query ($connect,$query_del)or die (mysqli_error($connect));
        mysqli_query ($connect,$query_upd)or die (mysqli_error($connect));
        mysqli_query ($connect,$query_last)or die (mysqli_error($connect));
        mysqli_close($connect);
    }
```